# how to wrap the the text in the pdf output file

Tags: google-apps-script

I have converted a temporary google sheet to pdf with exportOptions. However, I want to keep the font size for the text fixed. This causes the text in each row to spill over to the next page. I believe using text wrapping might solve that but I don't know what the code for it is and don't know how to use it in the codes either. I am a novice in programming.

I have tried using commands such as font size, wrap, text-wrap, researched using google and read the documentation for exportOptions, blob, and text sizing as well.

```
const url = 
'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', 
target_ss);
const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    '&size=A4' + // paper size legal / letter / A4
    '&portrait=false' + // orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=false' + // fit to page width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=true' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions + target_sheet_Id, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }});

var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
var newFile = folder.createFile(blob);
```

No error messages but no change in output either probably because those commands don't apply for the exportOptions format.

Comment: Try [setWrap](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setwrapiswrapenabled)

Comment: Thanks Cooper, that works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through your cells and set the cell wrap of each cell to true using [`Range.setWrap(true)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setwrapiswrapenabled):

```gas
  var target_ss = "your-spreadsheet-id";
  var ss_sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(target_ss).getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < ss_sheets.length; i++){    
    Logger.log(ss_sheets[i].getDataRange().setWrap(true));
  }
```